# How do I plot only a table in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

Is it possible to draw only a table with matplotlib? If I uncomment the line

```
plt.bar(index, data[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[row])
```

of this example [code](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/table_demo.html), the plot is still visible. I want to have a table on top of my (PyQt) window and underneath a plot (with some space in between).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you just wanted to change the [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/table_demo.html) and put the table at the top, then `loc='top'` in the table declaration is what you need,

```
the_table = ax.table(cellText=cell_text,
                      rowLabels=rows,
                      rowColours=colors,
                      colLabels=columns,
                      loc='top')
```

Then adjusting the plot with,

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, top=0.8)
```

A more flexible option is to put the table in its own axis using subplots,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, axs =plt.subplots(2,1)
clust_data = np.random.random((10,3))
collabel=("col 1", "col 2", "col 3")
axs[0].axis('tight')
axs[0].axis('off')
the_table = axs[0].table(cellText=clust_data,colLabels=collabel,loc='center')

axs[1].plot(clust_data[:,0],clust_data[:,1])
plt.show()
```

which looks like this,

[image]

You are then free to adjust the locations of the axis as [required](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).

Comment: I want 1 table and 2 graphs below that, can we do that.

Comment: @vinayak_narune, yes, use `fig, axs =plt.subplots(3,1)`

Comment: Hi, I have many columns (over 20) and this solution causes that the content of my table is extremely small, changing font doesn't help, neither changing the dimensions. Is there a way to program the table to adjust the size to the content?

Comment: @Marta, you can add `fontsize=fs` in as an extra argument to table, where trying different `fs` values might work (see https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html). It would be best to ask a new question if you can't work this out.

Answer (score 88):

This is another option to write a pandas dataframe directly into a matplotlib table:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# hide axes
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - a little off topic, but I seem to be heading off into less trodden areas.  Any chance you know how to style this table to have alternating grey rows?

Comment: It looks like matploltib table has the `cellColours` option (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html). If it's not clear how to do this alternating, think a new question is best

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this is already answered, but if you want only a table in a figure window, then you can hide the axes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Hide axes
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

# Table from Ed Smith answer
clust_data = np.random.random((10,3))
collabel=("col 1", "col 2", "col 3")
ax.table(cellText=clust_data,colLabels=collabel,loc='center')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can di this:

```
#axs[1].plot(clust_data[:,0],clust_data[:,1]) # Remove this if you don't need it
axs[1].axis("off")  # This will leave the table alone in the window
```