# Apply CSS class to Pandas DataFrame using to_html

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble applying "classes" argument with Pandas "to_html" method to style a DataFrame.

"classes : str or list or tuple, default None
CSS class(es) to apply to the resulting html table"
from: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

I am able to render a styled DataFrame like this (for example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

myhtml = df.style.set_properties(**{'font-size': '11pt', 'font-family': 'Calibri','border-collapse': 'collapse','border': '1px solid black'}).render()

with open('myhtml.html','w') as f:
    f.write(myhtml)
```

How can I style html output from a DataFrame using "classes" with "to_html" like this:

```
df.to_html('myhtml.html',classes=<something here>)
```

Comment: How do you want the html file to look like?

Comment: I would like to apply the same properties that were given in the "set_properties" method in the example.

Comment: Create a string `"<style type='text/css'>" + myStyles + "</style>"` and append it to the string given by `df.to_html()`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Pandas' `to_html` simply outputs a large string containing HTML table markup. The classes argument is a convenience handler to give the `<table>` a *class* attribute that will be referenced in a **previously created** CSS document that styles it. Therefore, incorporate `to_html` into a wider HTML document build that references an external CSS.

Interestingly, `to_html` adds dual classes `<table class="dataframe mystyle">` which can be referenced in CSS individually, `.dataframe {...} .mystyle{...}`, or together `.dataframe.mystyle {...}`. Below demonstrates with random data.

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')

np.random.seed(6182018)
demo_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-06-18', freq='D'), 50),
                        'analysis_tool': np.random.choice(['pandas', 'r', 'julia', 'sas', 'stata', 'spss'],50),              
                        'database': np.random.choice(['postgres', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'oracle', 'sql server', 'db2'],50), 
                        'os': np.random.choice(['windows 10', 'ubuntu', 'mac os', 'android', 'ios', 'windows 7', 'debian'],50), 
                        'num1': np.random.randn(50)*100,
                        'num2': np.random.uniform(0,1,50),                   
                        'num3': np.random.randint(100, size=50),
                        'bool': np.random.choice([True, False], 50)
                       },
                        columns=['date', 'analysis_tool', 'num1', 'database', 'num2', 'os', 'num3', 'bool']
          )


print(demo_df.head(10))
#      date    analysis_tool     num1      database     num2        os      num3  bool 
# 0 2018-04-21     pandas     153.474246       mysql  0.658533         ios   74    True
# 1 2018-04-13        sas     199.461669      sqlite  0.656985   windows 7   11   False
# 2 2018-06-09      stata      12.918608      oracle  0.495707     android   25   False
# 3 2018-04-24       spss      88.562111  sql server  0.113580   windows 7   42   False
# 4 2018-05-05       spss     110.231277      oracle  0.660977  windows 10   76    True
# 5 2018-04-05        sas     -68.140295  sql server  0.346894  windows 10    0    True
# 6 2018-05-07      julia      12.874660    postgres  0.195217         ios   79    True
# 7 2018-01-22          r     189.410928       mysql  0.234815  windows 10   56   False
# 8 2018-01-12     pandas    -111.412564  sql server  0.580253      debian   30   False
# 9 2018-04-12          r      38.963967    postgres  0.266604   windows 7   46   False
```

**CSS** *(save as df_style.css)*

```
/* includes alternating gray and white with on-hover color */

.mystyle {
    font-size: 11pt; 
    font-family: Arial;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border: 1px solid silver;

}

.mystyle td, th {
    padding: 5px;
}

.mystyle tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #E0E0E0;
}

.mystyle tr:hover {
    background: silver;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Pandas**

```
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')   # FOR TABLE <th>

html_string = '''
<html>
  <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
  <body>
    {table}
  </body>
</html>.
'''

# OUTPUT AN HTML FILE
with open('myhtml.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_string.format(table=demo_df.to_html(classes='mystyle')))
```

---

**OUTPUT**

**HTML** *(references df_style.css, assumed in same directory; see class argument in table)*

```xml
<html>
  <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
  <body>
    <table border="1" class="dataframe mystyle">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th></th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>analysis_tool</th>
      <th>num1</th>
      <th>database</th>
      <th>num2</th>
      <th>os</th>
      <th>num3</th>
      <th>bool</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>2018-04-21</td>
      <td>pandas</td>
      <td>153.474246</td>
      <td>mysql</td>
      <td>0.658533</td>
      <td>ios</td>
      <td>74</td>
      <td>True</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2018-04-13</td>
      <td>sas</td>
      <td>199.461669</td>
      <td>sqlite</td>
      <td>0.656985</td>
      <td>windows 7</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>False</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>2018-06-09</td>
      <td>stata</td>
      <td>12.918608</td>
      <td>oracle</td>
      <td>0.495707</td>
      <td>android</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>False</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>2018-04-24</td>
      <td>spss</td>
      <td>88.562111</td>
      <td>sql server</td>
      <td>0.113580</td>
      <td>windows 7</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>False</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>2018-05-05</td>
      <td>spss</td>
      <td>110.231277</td>
      <td>oracle</td>
      <td>0.660977</td>
      <td>windows 10</td>
      <td>76</td>
      <td>True</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: HTML Output]

Comment: Thanks, it's confusing since one needs to reference the .css file in an "html_string" before using it's classes with "to_html". Seems like there should be a way to specify the .css file from the argument directly.

Comment: I think the confusion is really with pandas authors labeling the method `to_html()` when really it is `to_html_table_string()`. A full HTML document is not produced with this method and *class* is a special attribute created in `<table>` output. Plus, *class* is not reserved for just CSS but can be used in Javascript/JQuery and others.

Comment: df.to_html(myhtml.html) will produce a simple html table of the dataframe that can be opened in a browser. Is that not a "full html document"?

Comment: Not it is not. Check page source and you will see `<html>`, `<body>`, and other tags are missing even though your browser renders a table.

Comment: is there a way i can add a caption to the table printed from data frame?

Comment: @Parfait - Is it possible to add tags to `<tr>`s and `<td>`s of the table rendered using `df.to_html()`?

Comment: If by tags you mean class or id attributes at those levels, I do not believe so as this method is basic to only render simple `<table>` markup. Please read docs for more info: [Dataframe.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html).

Comment: You need imgkit.from_file('table_report.html', 'table_report.jpg',config=config,options={'enable-local-file-access': ''})  for local file access.

Comment: @Parfait Hi, your answer is great. Now the only issue is, when I email the `myhtml.html` file, it looses all the formatting. I presume that's because the CSS file is no longer in the same folder. Is there a way to do it where you don't lose the formatting?

Comment: Since 2018, there have been many changes in `pandas.Styler` for adding CSS styles and structuring the HTML output. Please review the documentation, since much of this answer may now not be necessary.

Answer (score 14):

Essentially, the pandas.to_html() just exports a plain HTML table. You can insert the table wherever you want in the body and control the style via CSS in the style section.

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
  table, th, td {{font-size:10pt; border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:left;}}
  th, td {{padding: 5px;}}
</style>
</head>
<body>
{
  pandas.to_html()
}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this method works the best for me as i use imgkit to produce pngs for pdf reports

Comment: Where is the style section?

Answer (score 8):

I found the most precise, and frankly the easiest way of doing it is skipping the styling, to_html() etc. and converting the DF to a dictionary using the df.to_dict() method.

Specifically what gave me trouble, was displaying the styled pandas html in an outlook email, as it just wouldn't render properly with the css mess that pandas was producing.

iterate over the dict and generate the html there by simply wrapping keys/values in the tags that you need, adding classes etc. and concatenate this all into one string. 
Then paste this str into a prepared template with a predefined css.

For convenience I found it's useful to export the same df twice, using .to_dict() and to_dict('index') to first fill in the columns and then work your way down row by row. Alternatively just have a list of relevant column names.

```
dict_data = [df.to_dict(), df.to_dict('index')]

return_str = '<table><tr>'

for key in dict_data[0].keys():
    return_str = return_str + '<th class="header">' + key + '</th>'

return_str = return_str + '</tr>'

for key in dict_data[1].keys():
    return_str = return_str + '<tr><th class="index">' + key + '</th>'
    for subkey in dict_data[1][key]:
        return_str = return_str + '<td>' + dict_data[1][key][subkey] + '</td>'

return_str = return_str + '</tr></table>'
```

and then return_str goes into the template.

Comment: Yes after struggling yesterday and today using  a lot of jquery to style it, add attributes and classes. Agreed.

Answer (score 4):

Credit to [Ku Tang Pan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7325557/ku-tang-pan)'s answer for this - I was able to customize their solution to something even more precise. I personally like to conditionally format my tables based on certain values.

I find that generating your own HTML is the most precise way and gives you full control.

```
##note how any row that has the drop alert flag set to "Y" will be formatted yellow:

dict_data = [df.to_dict(), df.to_dict('index')]

htmldf = '<table><tr>'

for key in dict_data[0].keys():
    htmldf = htmldf + '<th class="header">' + key + '</th>'

htmldf = htmldf + '</tr>'

for key in dict_data[1].keys():
    htmldf = htmldf + '<tr '
    htmldf = htmldf + 'style="font-weight: bold; background-color: yellow">' if dict_data[1][key]['drop_alert'] == 'Y' else htmldf + '>'
    for subkey in dict_data[1][key]:
        htmldf = htmldf + '<td>' + str(dict_data[1][key][subkey]) + '</td>'
    htmldf = htmldf + '</tr>'

htmldf = htmldf + '</tr></table>'

# Write html object to a file (adjust file path; Windows path is used here)
with open('C:\\Users\\Documents\\test.html','wb') as f:
    f.write(htmldf.encode("UTF-8"))
```

**Result:** neatly conditionally formatted table

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it

Create a text file for css code and write down your css code here, say css_style.txt
Now read this txt file as a string in your python file

`with open('css_style.txt', 'r') as myfile:
     style = myfile.read()`

Now in HTML code

```
"""<html><head>Something Something</head>{1}<div>{0}</div></html>""".format(some_panda_dataframe.to_html,style)
```

Here in my case css_style.txt file is

```
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #FFD5D5}

th {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to my early `to_html` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50939211/1422451), the new Pandas 1.3.0+ [**`to_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html) can render HTML documents using only stylesheets, namely CSS and XSLT, without any string formatting.

While the XSLT will be a bit involved to replicate the same HTML table design, it is open-ended for user-defined changes.

**Data**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1032022)
demo_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31', freq='D'), 50),
    'analysis_tool': np.random.choice(['pandas', 'r', 'julia', 'sas', 'stata', 'spss'],50),
    'num1': np.random.randn(50)*100,
    'database': np.random.choice(['postgres', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'oracle', 'sql server', 'db2'],50),
    'num2': np.random.uniform(0,1,50),
    'os': np.random.choice(['windows 10', 'ubuntu', 'mac os', 'android', 'ios', 'windows 7', 'debian'],50),                    
    'num3': np.random.randint(100, size=50),
    'bool': np.random.choice([True, False], 50)
})

print(demo_df.head(10))
#         date analysis_tool        num1  ...          os  num3   bool
# 0 2021-05-02         stata   52.370960  ...  windows 10    36  False
# 1 2021-03-16        pandas -135.411727  ...     android    74  False
# 2 2021-12-17           sas  -56.823191  ...      debian    75  False
# 3 2021-11-11        pandas  -32.575253  ...      debian    33  False
# 4 2021-11-19         julia  176.464891  ...      mac os    63   True
# 5 2021-12-30             r  -82.874595  ...      ubuntu    52   True
# 6 2021-03-27             r   63.897578  ...     android    56  False
# 7 2021-03-14         julia  -75.117220  ...      mac os     6  False
# 8 2021-04-09          spss -302.664890  ...         ios    97   True
# 9 2021-03-15          spss  -12.014122  ...         ios    27   True
```

**CSS** *(save as DataFrameStyle.css)*

```css
/* includes alternating gray and white with on-hover color */

.mystyle {
    font-size: 11pt; 
    font-family: Arial;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border: 1px solid silver;

}

.mystyle td, th {
    padding: 5px;
}

.mystyle tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #E0E0E0;
}

.mystyle tr:hover {
    background: silver;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**XSLT** *(save as DataFrameStyle.xsl; references .css)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/data">
      <html>
        <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataFrameStyle.css"/>
        <body>
          <table border="1" class="dataframe mystyle">
            <thead>
                <tr style="text-align: center;">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="row[1]/*" mode="headers"/>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row[1]/*" mode="headers">
        <th><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></th>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></tr>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="row/*">
       <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Pandas**

```py
demo_df.to_xml(
    "/path/to/Output.html",
    stylesheet = "DataFrameStyle.xsl"
)
```

**Output**

[image: HTML Table Output]

Answer (score 1):

#### Since pandas `to_html` lacked functionality

Using the code bellow you can repeat columns as `<tr>` attributes, that's essential for stilling, writing events etc.

**Arguments**

- `row_attrs` (list, optional): List of columns to write as attributes in row `<tr>`element. Defaults to none.
- `row_cols` (list, optional): List of columns to write as children in row element that is `<td>` elements. Defaults to all columns.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def dataframe_to_html(df, row_attrs=[], row_cols=None):
    """
    Converts dataframe to an html <table> as an ElementTree class.  
        * df (pandas.DataFrame): table
        * row_attrs (list, optional): List of columns to write as attributes in <tr> row element. Defaults to [] none.
        * row_cols (list, optional): List of columns to write as children in row <td> element. Defaults to all columns.               
    - returns: ElementTree class containing an html <table>      
    Note: generate a string with `etree.tostring(dataframe_to_html(...), encoding='unicode', method='xml')`
    """
    if not row_cols: # default to use all columns as sub-elements of row
        row_cols = df.columns.to_list()   
    table = df.astype(str) # turns everything on str
    table_dict = table.to_dict('split')
    col2index = { v:i for i, v in enumerate(table_dict['columns']) }    
    def add_rows(root, table_dict, row_attrs_, row_cols_, tag_row='tr', tag_col='td'):            
        for row in table_dict:
            # row attrs names and values in lower-case (key:value)
            row_attrs = { key.lower(): row[col2index[key]].lower() for key in row_attrs_ } 
            erow = etree.SubElement(root, tag_row, attrib=row_attrs) 
            for col in row_cols_:
                ecol = etree.SubElement(erow, tag_col)
                ecol.text = str(row[col2index[col]])
    etable = etree.Element('table')
    thead = etree.SubElement(etable, 'thead') 
    add_rows(thead, [table_dict['columns']], [], row_cols, 'tr', 'th')
    tbody = etree.SubElement(etable, 'tbody')     
    add_rows(tbody, table_dict['data'], row_attrs, row_cols)
    return etable
```

#### Usage

```
...
# manipulate your dataframe and create `row_attrs` and `row_cols`
html_table = dataframe_to_html(table, row_attrs, row_cols)
# then convert your etree to string to use on flask template for example
html_table = etree.tostring(html_table, encoding='unicode', method='xml')
render_template('index.html', pandas_table=html_table...) # your template variables
```

**Note:** the `<tr>` row attribute names are created in lower-case.

Further suggestion: Additional customization on the table can be done still using the `ElementTree` from `etree` package.

Answer (score 0):

"***table_id***" is a parameter which allows inclusion of a css id in df.to-html()

example:

```
df.to_html(df_html_path,table_id = ".df #tableFormat" )
```

Now the *css_id*(.df #tableFormat) has to be linked to the *main_html* file and then one can import this exported df.to_html file as an *iframe*.

*example*(include below lines in code):

***df_css.css***

```
.df #tableFormat{
    show_dimensions : True;
    bold_rows : True;
    justify:center;}
```

***main_html.html*** (link df_css to main_html):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="df_css.css"/>
```

***main_html.html*** (link df_html to main_html):

```
<iframe  src="df_html_path"></iframe >
```