# How to get single line border with pandas df.to_html?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas

I am exporting pandas dataframe as table in html , exported to outlook.
The table appears fine but the double cell borders are not good, I want a single line border, check the attached screenshot and code.
[image]

```
df[['Col1','col2']].to_html( header=True, index=False, na_rep='NaN', formatters=None,  sparsify=None, index_names=True, justify=None,  classes=None, notebook=False, border=1, table_id=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace border 1 to 0 if you **must** use border.

`to_html().replace('border="1"','border="0"')`

However, the border attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807744/apply-css-class-to-pandas-dataframe-using-to-html) would be ideal for you.

Comment: This is same as making border=0 in above code, output is no border at all

Comment: Yes. Forget `border` in is no longer part of the HTML5 standard. Use CSS.