# Removing "row index" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the below dataframe wherein I am trying to remove the first column which is the default column assigned in pandas dataframe/series. How do I get rid of that?

[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQcK0.png)

Actual result should be without the first column which has the "0".
I have tried using reset index with drop but nothing works.

Here is my code which sends a mail with the dataframe output.

```html
def send_email(index):
    fromaddr = ""
    toaddr = ""
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Timestamp Alarm"
    df1 = df.iloc[index,1:]
    new = df1

    body = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    {0}
  </body>
</html>
""".format(pd.DataFrame(new).T.to_html())
    part1 = MIMEText(body,'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login('***', '**')
    server.sendmail('','',msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at *to_html* documentation.

This fuction contains a.o. *index* parameter (default *True*),
deciding whether to generate the index column.

Maybe you should pass it with *False* value.

**Another option**:

Print the DataFrame (and then send) as "ordinary" text.

To hide the index column, also pass *index=False*:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have already figured it out though. Do you know how I can add styles to to_html? For eg. Justify columns and values?

Comment: I found some description concerning adding classes at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807744/apply-css-class-to-pandas-dataframe-using-to-html

Comment: `output1.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)` works similarly for csv as well

Answer (score 0):

See the following and relate to your problem.

### Generic Solution

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'Field_A': 'FA', 'Field_B': 'FB', 'Field_C': 'FC'}
df = pd.DataFrame({0: d}).T
df
```

**Output**:

```
    Field_A Field_B Field_C
0   FA      FB      FC
```

#### Specific Solution

If all you want is the cell values for columns `Field_A`, `Field_B`, `Field_C`, then just call `df.loc[0]`. In your case, you would need to change the line where you define variable `new`.

```py
new = df.loc[index]
```