# How do I make a pandas table align to center when using to_html()

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe,

`result_df.round(2).to_html(r"C:\example.html", justify="center", col_space=750)`

The resulting html table has centered column names and row names but the numbers in the table are left-aligned. How do I get the entries in the table also to be left aligned?

many thanks.

Comment: You may want to try by applying CSS classes and this link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807744/apply-css-class-to-pandas-dataframe-using-to-html

Comment: @PavanKumarPolavarapu this is interesting. thanks