# Saving a pandas DataFrame to html but using the classes parameter

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, class

I tried different approaches to use the "classes" parameter of the to_html method, without success. The documentation seems a little unclear, it just says that it should be string, list or tuple, but I can find how to actually provide the css code to style the tables. This [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882993/how-to-apply-css-class-my-style-to-pandas-dataframe-using-to-html) answer, and other like that use a workaround, but they don't actually save the DataFrame to a file. Any help would be truly appreciated