# I would like to pass raw HTML to QWebEngineView but getting errors

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

abc = pd.read_csv("filepath")

web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(abc.to_html())

web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Try `web.setHtml(abc.to_html())` instead of `web.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(abc.to_html())`

Comment: you can find the same thing in above code.

Comment: Why not loading the CSV directly into the `WebEngineView` ?

Comment: @suryaambati what same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to load html then you must use the [`setHtml()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setHtml) method:

```
web.setHtml(abc.to_html())
```

Comment: Thanks you its working but do you have any idea how to add css file as well?

Comment: @suryaambati See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807744/apply-css-class-to-pandas-dataframe-using-to-html/50939211