# Custom html table in streamlit

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, streamlit

I am trying to render a custom html table that is styled with css. I can get my table loaded, but the referenced css file is not used for some reason. Here's an example of my html code

```
<html>
    <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
    <body>
        <table border="1" class="dataframe mystyle">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th></th>
      <th>team</th>
      <th>player</th>
      <th>week</th>
      <th>year</th>
      <th>x</th>
      <th>y</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td><img src="https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/kc.png" width="40" style="text-align: center"></td>
      <td><img src="https://static.www.nfl.com/image/private/f_auto,q_auto/league/xw0jhb7zeobj4bkxfpwg" width="75" style="text-align: center"></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2020</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </body>
    </html>.
```

here is how I generated this html using pandas

```
html_string = """
    <html>
    <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
    <body>
        {table}
    </body>
    </html>.
    """
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components
import pandas as pd

html_string.format(
            table=df.to_html(
                classes="mystyle",
                escape=False,
                formatters=format_dict,
                justify="center",
            )
        )
```

and here is my css file, `df_style.css` that is in the same directory as my streamlit app file

```
.mystyle {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid rgb(237, 69, 69);

}
```

and here is how I rendered the table via streamlit

```
    components.html(
        html_string.format(
            table=df.to_html(
                classes="mystyle",
                escape=False,
                formatters=format_dict,
                justify="center",
            )
        ),
    )
```

but the table just renders with default html table styling rather than referencing my css. [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807744/apply-css-class-to-pandas-dataframe-using-to-html) notes that pandas `*.to_html()` "adds dual classes `<table class="dataframe mystyle">` which can be referenced in CSS individually, `.dataframe {...} .mystyle{...}` , or together `.dataframe.mystyle {...}`" but I still can't get the streamlit to reference my css file when using any of those naming conventions for the css classes in my file. Any ideas? This should be possible considering [the example in the documentation](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api) references a bootstrap css file.

**EDIT: per [this post](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/cant-import-local-css-and-local-jss-in-streamlit-v1-components-html/15345) on the streamlit forms, I was able to get the css to render by putting it in the `static` streamlit folder. Now the question is will the css still render correctly if I just have all my files in a github repo?**

Comment: if you have files on different server then you should use full URL - with domain - `href="https://other_computer.com/correct/path/df_style.css"`

Comment: how do you want to run code on github repo? Maybe you should first try and later ask question.