# How to save pdfs

Tags: python, pandas

How could I save dfa as a pdf?
So far I was able to have each of the elements saved separately in each file. How now can I have the whole file saved as a single pdf?

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'STREAM':['EAGLE','HAWK','HAWK','HAWK','EAGLE','HAWK','EAGLE'],'MAT':['A','D','F','D','C','C','E'],'KIS':['B','D','E','D','A','C','D'],'GEO':['B','C','E','E','F','A','B']})

dfa.to_csv('results.csv',index=False)

students_data = csv.reader(open("results.csv", 'r'))

for row in students_data:
    STREAM = row[0]
    MAT = row[1]
    GEO = row[2]
    KIS = row[3]

c = canvas.Canvas(MAT +".pdf")
c.drawString(60, 700, "STREAM:  " + STREAM)
c.drawString(60, 600, "MAT:  " + MAT)
c.drawString(60, 500, "KIS:  " + KIS)
c.drawString(60, 400, "GEO:  " + GEO)
c.save()
```

Comment: Have you seen this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155776/export-pandas-dataframe-into-a-pdf-file-using-python?

Comment: @Balaji, It did not sort my concern really. I saw it.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to create a blank PDF as your template page and then
merge the new PDF to it

```
packet = io.BytesIO()

# Create the initial canvas.
c = canvas.Canvas(packet)

# your code for adding to the canvas

packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
# Import The Template
template = PdfFileReader(open('path_to_template'), "rb")
output = PdfFileWriter()

# add the created PDF as a watermark to the template
page = template.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))

output.addPage(page)
# finally, write "output" to a real file
outputStream = open(output_path, "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

you will need these imports

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
```

Comment: Please remove the trailing ) in template = PdfFileReader(open('path_to_template'), "rb"))

Comment: What do I import for it to work? I have this imported already.  from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

Comment: @Ptar I included the imports in the answer at the bottom.

Comment: This code returns this error PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Cannot read an empty file