# python excel sheet saves as pdf

Tags: python, excel, pdf

I want to save my excel sheets (there are more than 50 sheets) in a separate PDF file and each file name should be saved in the sheet name. I can do it by excel VBA but I was curious whether it can be done in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export Pandas DataFrame into a PDF file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155776/export-pandas-dataframe-into-a-pdf-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

pywin32 will do the job for you. Please follow [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-excel-to-pdf-using-python/).