# python pandas generate pdf file from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

We can easily export pandas dataframe to csv file. Please find the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/ashy/Downloads/weather_data.csv');
df.to_csv('/Users/ashy/Downloads/file1.csv');
```

Is there an easy way to generate pdf file from dataframe. There isn't any method available to do so. What alternate methods can we use to generate file from a dataframe ? Please let me know.

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export Pandas DataFrame into a PDF file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155776/export-pandas-dataframe-into-a-pdf-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

This method requires the **reportlab** library to be installed.

The below code should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/ashy/Downloads/weather_data.csv')

def df_to_pdf(df, filename):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(filename, pagesize=letter)
    elements = []
    t = Table(df.values.tolist())
    elements.append(t)
    doc.build(elements)

df_to_pdf(df, '/Users/ashy/Downloads/weather_data.pdf')
```

Comment: there isn't any to_pfd method available. Pls find the documentation below:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: getting the following error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_pdf'

Comment: the above solution works. PDF file is getting generated. Do you know how to preserve table headers and margins. Pls let me know.