# Python library to display interview questions results (stored in excel)

Tags: python, excel, formatting

I have this excel file which contains interview answers, a lot of them, where every row is one interview.
I want an easy way to display each row, perhaps in a popup window so I won’t have to play with the row and column sizes each time I review answers.
Currently I’m using a pandas DataFrame to get all the data from the file
Does anybody know some library or way to display these things (before I burn my eyes looking at this excel file  )
Thank you

Example for the excel

| Interviewee|     Question 1       |
| ------———— | ------—————————————- |
|   John     |  a really long answer|
|   Dell     | a really short answer|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the simplest would be to use [`DataFrame.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) from Pandas, to convert the table into an HTML  formatted table (check out the documentation to see settings of this command). The provided HTML you can save as a file and open with a browser or visualize the HTML in Jupyter or any other library.

There's also [`DataFrame.to_markdown()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html)

Or you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574470/8564999) to generate a PDF file

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"q":[15,12,13],"a":[
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sollicitudin est quis massa sagittis euismod. Proin lacus sapien, tempus sed tempor eget, viverra hendrerit lorem. Curabitur nec vulputate lorem. Cras condimentum ligula non purus pharetra egestas. Praesent et hendrerit sem, sit amet lacinia odio. Nunc feugiat nibh ut tellus tempus, sit amet convallis nibh sodales. Quisque ac ligula non lacus ullamcorper vestibulum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris aliquam pretium nisl, nec pretium dui malesuada in. Etiam vitae dui egestas, pulvinar orci sagittis, gravida libero. Curabitur interdum dui et consectetur cursus. Maecenas neque dolor, egestas ut laoreet non, rutrum id urna.",
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sollicitudin est quis massa sagittis euismod. Proin lacus sapien, tempus sed tempor eget, viverra hendrerit lorem. Curabitur nec vulputate lorem. Cras condimentum ligula non purus pharetra egestas. Praesent et hendrerit sem, sit amet lacinia odio. Nunc feugiat nibh ut tellus tempus, sit amet convallis nibh sodales.",
]})
print(df.to_html())
```

This outputs this HTML

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>q</th>
      <th>a</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sollicitudin est quis massa sagittis euismod. Proin lacus sapien, tempus sed tempor eget, viverra hendrerit lorem. Curabitur nec vulputate lorem. Cras condimentum ligula non purus pharetra egestas. Praesent et hendrerit sem, sit amet lacinia odio. Nunc feugiat nibh ut tellus tempus, sit amet convallis nibh sodales. Quisque ac ligula non lacus ullamcorper vestibulum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris aliquam pretium nisl, nec pretium dui malesuada in. Etiam vitae dui egestas, pulvinar orci sagittis, gravida libero. Curabitur interdum dui et consectetur cursus. Maecenas neque dolor, egestas ut laoreet non, rutrum id urna.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sollicitudin est quis massa sagittis euismod. Proin lacus sapien, tempus sed tempor eget, viverra hendrerit lorem. Curabitur nec vulputate lorem. Cras condimentum ligula non purus pharetra egestas. Praesent et hendrerit sem, sit amet lacinia odio. Nunc feugiat nibh ut tellus tempus, sit amet convallis nibh sodales.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Which after viewing in browser looks like this
[image]