# How to write table structure data in PDF file in python?

Tags: python, reportlab

```
+----+-----------------------------+
| id | name                        |
+====+=============================+
| 47 | Some textjogjwojgopwgpowmok |
+----+-----------------------------+
| 47 | Some textjogjwojgopwgpowmokg|
+----+-----------------------------+
| 47 | Some textjogjwojgopwgpowmokg|
+----+-----------------------------+
| 47 | Some textjogjwojgopwgpowmokg|
+----+-----------------------------+
| 47 | Some textjogjwojgopwgpowmokg|
+----+-----------------------------+
```

I want to write the above table in PDF file in above format using python libraries. Appreciate immediate response.

Answer (score 8):

You can [generate the table using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137396/matplotlib-table-only) and [save it to PDF from matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#save-multiple-plots-to-one-pdf-file). There's also [reportlab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab).

Comment: I will be getting data as same format, so i don't want create table format and all. I just want to write same exact data which i posted

Comment: If I understand correctly what you basically want is to write a string to pdf. Try [reportlab](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf)