# Matplotlib Table Show Only Some Lines

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Given the following table (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45936469/4392566)):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I want to hide all lines save for those horizontal under each row (but not the bottom or top 2 rows). Is this level of control attainable?
I tried ax.hlines, but the lines seemed to plot randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the "*but not the bottom or top 2 rows*", can you specify?

Yet, to get only the horizontal lines, you can add the `edges='horizontal'` parameter:

```
ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center', edges='horizontal')
```

output:
[image: horizontal lines]

Comment: Thanks! From here, can you make it to the top and bottom lines (edges) do not appear?