# How do I change the font size of the data in the table in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have taken one of the solutions from this page
[How do I plot only a table in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137396/how-do-i-plot-only-a-table-in-matplotlib)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# hide axes
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

adding this didn't make any difference to the font size

```
ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center',fontsize=14)
```

how else can I change the size?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line before `plt.show`:

```py
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
```

Comment: nope that didnt work

Comment: Weird, it worked for me with your code. Have you tried the proposed solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39566040/10056232

Comment: not sure if thats helpful, I think I got the answer but the index of the dataframe is causing issues. am going to close this Qs and start another thread.